# How can I customise plank?

Tags: plank, settings

The Desktop plug in settings only lets you choose between two icon sizes and the hide behavior. I would like to be able to change the settings with more control than that. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Hi Bill, if one of these answers solved your issue, remember to mark it with the checkmark so it'll be promoted accordingly

Comment: I want plank not to hide but i dont want it cutting a whole chunk of the app I'm on
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkdDF.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNto5.png

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Plank has a hidden settings window for developers/OEMs.

1. Hold down <kbd>Control</kbd> and right click anywhere on the dock
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Go nuts

Please be aware that some of these options will lead to less-than-optimal experiences. For example, setting the dock to the Top position will make it impossible to unhide in certain situations as well as cover the time, etc. Some of these features are not completely implemented or don't fully work with other parts of the desktop environment or with certain hardware.

Comment: ah, I always used to right-click on the edge of plank to get there, didn't know I could just hold ctrl - cool, thanks :)

Comment: This does not work on Juno, control right-click merely opens the icons present on the dock.

Answer (score 7):

It is quite easy to fine-tune the settings of Plank.

Navigate to `~/.config/plank/dock` and open the `settings` file in your preferred text editor. You can view hidden folders by pressing `Ctrl+H`.
Scroll down to near the end of the file, and change the line that `ShowDockItem=false` to `true`.

Click on the Plank icon that will appear on the left, and you will see the settings dialog:
[image: Plank settings]

Answer (score 6):

Run

```
plank --preferences
```

This will also work in other distros.

Answer (score 0):

you could install gnome tweaks, this app lets you "tweak" a lot of things including plank

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

[image]

Comment: This is not gnome-tweak-tool. This is the unmaintained elementary-tweaks.