# What are hidden settings/features available in elementary OS freya

Tags: release-freya

After reading a post [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/how-can-i-customise-plank/2690#2690) by [Daniel Foré](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9?tab=profile), I am just curious to know the *hidden* settings/features in elementary OS (freya) ?

Is there any documentation available for these hidden features in freya?

Comment: I am wondering if elementary OS has any Easter eggs